# Unable to Understand Instrument data

Tags: xcode, ios7, instruments

Hi I am profiling my application with Instruments in order to

Find how much memory my Application is using.

I am downloading a file of around 100MB . and I am getting some strange data in instruments which i am unable to understand.

Can anyone help me understand the data shown by Instruments. (refer to Screenshot)

and How much memory my application is using in real ? (I am using iOS 7).

[image: Instrument Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focus on the Live Bytes column for All Heap Allocations to see how much memory your application is using. You cannot control your application's Anonymous VM size.

In your screenshot the Live Bytes column for All Heap Allocations is 3.36 MB, which is good. The Live Bytes column measures the amount of memory your application is currently using, but it does not include any allocated memory for OpenGL ES textures. You should also profile your application with the Memory Monitor instrument to determine how much memory your application is using.

To use the Memory Monitor instrument, click the Library button in the toolbar to get a list of available instruments. Drag the Memory Monitor instrument to the instrument list on the left side of the trace document window (Allocations and VM Tracker in your screenshot). Alternatively, you can choose the Activity Monitor template, click the Info button for the Activity Monitor instrument, and click the Configure button to tell the Activity Monitor instrument to list the physical memory used.